# Smoothing filter on multiple Matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matrix, filter

Normally I associate smoothing filters with images in 2 dimensions.
I have a group of Matrices in a variable `x1`. Of shape `(259,60,40)`
where each `(60,40)` is like a `BW` image.

I wanted to know if there are any filters that i can apply something like a filter across different strides or number of images and smooth the values.

For example:-

```
1 st Image         2 nd Image                      Result
0 0 0 1 1 0 0     0 0 0 1 1 0 0                  0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0     0 0 0 1 1 0 0  some operation  0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 --->0 0 0 1 1 0 0    ----- >       0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0 0 0                  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0     0 0 0 0 0 0 0                  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0     0 1 0 0 1 0 0                  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Some operation like this but where I can vary the number of images and the strength of this filter.

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from numpy import zeros, newaxis
import io
import math

f = open('/media/anilil/Data/Datasets/repo/txt_op/vid.txt','r')
x = np.loadtxt(f,dtype=np.uint8,comments='#',delimiter='\t')
nof = x.shape[0]/72 # Find the number of frames
x1 = x.reshape(-1,60,40)
```

Example [textfile](http://pastebin.com/VutTTTSM)

Comment: filters are to my understanding just a operation based on a kernel, which is applied to each position in your matrix. now you want to use the input of another picture with it. I imagine you could just calculate two independent kernels (one for each picture) and add those together?

Comment: A 3D convolution should do what you describe (ie, use a 3D kernel of your design and your image stack as a 3D array).

Comment: Got your points..  I could arrange the images as a 3d array and experiment with several sizes and arrangement of these kernels.. Just wanted to know if there was a similar/well documented example or people who had a similar problem.. Do let me know if u find some better solution :-)